# Looping through jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've got an associative array with jQuery objects that I want to loop over to set a value on each.

I'm relatively new to JavaScript / jQuery, but this is what I tried without any luck:

```
var inputs = [
    { key: "firstName",         val: $("#signup input[name=firstName]") },
    { key: "lastName",          val: $("#signup input[name=lastName]") },
    { key: "email",             val: $("#signup input[name=email]") },
    { key: "confirmationEmail", val: $("#signup input[name=confirmationEmail]") },
    { key: "password",          val: $("#signup input[name=password]") },
    { key: "terms",             val: $("#signup input[name=terms]") }
];

inputs.each(function() {
    $(this).val("test");
});
```

Comment: you ain't saying what you wanna do..

Comment: `inputs` is an array, not a jQuery object, so you cannot apply the `each()` method to it. You can, however, use the `$.each()` function instead, but you still will not be able to apply `val()` to the items themselves (since they're plain objects).

Comment: Are you aware that you only need a selector to go through all of them? Why are you using an Array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In newer browsers you don't need jQuery for that:

```
inputs.forEach(function(input) {
    console.log("key is " + input.key);
    input.val.val("test");
});
```

The `.forEach()` method is built-in. If you must use jQuery`.s`.each()` it'd look like this:

```
$.each(inputs, function(index, input) {
    console.log("key is " + input.key);
    input.val.val("test");
});
```

Note that the jQuery `$.each()` calls the callback function with the index of the element as the first argument and the element itself as the second. The native `.forEach()` passes those in reverse order.

Finally just as a note, you can set all the `<input>` values under the "signup" element with

```
$("#signup input").val("test");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.each(inputs, function(){ $(this).val("test")});
```